# How do I capture a tap on a custom card view in a ZStack?

Tags: animation, swiftui, gesture

I'm trying pretty hard to recreate something like the Wallet view, but cannot really figure it out. I've hard-coded offsets into my ZStack, but of course I want to avoid that too. It seems like the offsets are keeping the taps from registering at all. Here is my code so far, tapping a card should change its title's colour between white and yellow.

Eventually, of course, I want to add animations to the stack of cards and be able to "pull" one from it place to make it the primary view. But I have to figure out how to catch the taps first...

I used this video as a base, but it doesn't really go as far as I'd like:

https://nsscreencast.com/episodes/399-swiftui-transforms-and-animations

```
import SwiftUI

struct BetterCards: View {
    var body: some View {

        ScrollView (.vertical) {
                ZStack {
                    CardView(title: "adidas", color: .blue, offset: 0.0)
                    CardView(title: "Le Crueset", color: .pink, offset: 90.0)
                    CardView(title: " Card", color: .black, offset: 180.0)
                    CardView(title: "Sandusk", color: .orange, offset: 270.0)
            }
        }
    }
}


struct CardView: View {

    @State var isYellow: Bool = false

    let title: String
    let color: Color
    let offset: CGFloat

    var body: some View {


        Button(action: {
            self.isYellow.toggle()
        }) {
            ZStack {
                 Rectangle()
                    .fill(color)
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                    .frame(width: 320, height: 210)
                VStack {
                    Text(title)
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                        .bold()
                        .foregroundColor(isYellow ? .yellow : .white)
                        .padding()
                    Spacer()
                }

            }.shadow(radius: 2.0)
            .offset(x: 0, y: offset)

            }.onTapGesture {
            print("Tapped: \(self.title)")
        }
    }
}

struct BetterCards_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        BetterCards()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you both, Natalia and Mac3n

It got me thinking and I've ended up using a VStack

Happy to hear any comments. I'm not sure it's the best approach.

I've done away with the offsets and used two frames in the card view - one for the rectangle and one for the ZStack. I'm still trying to figure out the math for the .frame on the VStack however. It seems to be a multiple of the number of cards + the real height of a card, plus some variable I can't pin down.

```
import SwiftUI

struct BetterCards: View {

    let multiplier:CGFloat = 6

    var body: some View {

        ScrollView {
            Text("HEADER").background(Color(.blue))
            VStack {
                CardView(title: " Card", color: .black)
                CardView(title: "adidas", color: .blue)
                CardView(title: "Puma", color: .green)
                CardView(title: "Le Crueset", color: .yellow)
//                CardView(title: "adidas", color: .blue)
//                CardView(title: "OnlyLyon", color: .green)
//                CardView(title: "Le Crueset", color: .yellow)
                CardView(title: "adidas", color: .blue)
                CardView(title: "Sandusk", color: .orange)
//                CardView(title: "Le Crueset", color: .pink)
                }
            .frame(width: 400, height: multiplier * 60 + (430 - ( 52 )))
            .padding()
            .background(Color.gray)
            Text("FOOTER").background(Color(.blue))
        }
        .background(Color.yellow)
    }
}

struct CardView: View {

    @State var isYellow: Bool = false

    let title: String
    let color: Color

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
             Rectangle()
                .fill(color)
                .cornerRadius(10)
                .frame(width: 370, height: 430)
            VStack {
                Text(title)
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .bold()
                    .foregroundColor(isYellow ? .yellow : .white)
                    .padding()
                Spacer()
                }
        }
        .frame(width: 370, height: 60)
        .onTapGesture {
                self.isYellow.toggle()
                print("Tapped: \(self.title)")
        }
        .shadow(radius: 2.0)
    }
}

struct BetterCards_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        BetterCards()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {

        ScrollView (.vertical) {
            ZStack(alignment: .top) {
                CardView(title: "adidas", color: .blue, paddingOffset: 0)
                CardView(title: "Le Crueset", color: .pink, paddingOffset: 90)
                CardView(title: " Card", color: .black, paddingOffset: 180)
                CardView(title: "Sandusk", color: .orange, paddingOffset: 270)
            }
        }
    }
}


struct CardView: View {

    @State var isYellow: Bool = false

    let title: String
    let color: Color
    var paddingOffset: CGFloat

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Rectangle()
                .fill(color)
            VStack {
                Text(title)
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .bold()
                    .foregroundColor(isYellow ? .yellow : .white)
                    .padding()
                Spacer()
            }

        }.shadow(radius: 2.0)
            .cornerRadius(10)
            .frame(width: 320, height: 210)
            .padding(.top, paddingOffset)
            .onTapGesture {
                self.isYellow.toggle()
                print("Tapped: \(self.title)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check my answer, I edit it and using padding instead of offset. And in your card view, you don't need button, `onTapGesture` will handle it

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need both a `Button` and an `onTapGesture` on the same view. Your `CardView` is already a button, so it will register tap gestures. In order for it to function properly, I suggest you move the offset on the button itself. Also looks like it will register taps on all the views only if it has a sufficient height, so I set a frame on the button after setting an offset.
Overall the code would look something like this:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct BetterCards: View {
    var body: some View {

        ScrollView (.vertical) {
            ZStack(alignment: .top) {
                CardView(title: "adidas", color: .blue, offset: 0.0)
                CardView(title: "Le Crueset", color: .pink, offset: 90.0)
                CardView(title: " Card", color: .black, offset: 180.0)
                CardView(title: "Sandusk", color: .orange, offset: 270.0)
            }
        .padding()
        }
    }
}


struct CardView: View {

    @State var isYellow: Bool = false

    let title: String
    let color: Color
    let offset: CGFloat

    var body: some View {


        Button(action: {
            self.isYellow.toggle()
            print("Tapped: \(self.title)")
        }) {
            ZStack {
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(color)
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                    .frame(width: 320, height: 210)
                VStack {
                    Text(title)
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                        .bold()
                        .foregroundColor(isYellow ? .yellow : .white)
                        .padding()
                    Spacer()
                }
                .frame(width: 320, height: 210)

            }
            .shadow(radius: 2.0)

        }
        .offset(x: 0, y: offset)
        .frame(width: 320, height: 210 + offset, alignment: .top)
    }

}
```

You can play with alignment and padding on different views to get what you need.

Comment: Thanks, see my answer - it's quite different, so that's why I didn't reply it under your comment.